# If frequency is the characteristic of a source and remains constant why does it increase when tension of a string is increased?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, resonance

So as I've been taught, frequency is a characteristic of the source and it does not change. But, then there are questions where when the tension of a string increased and frequency increases. Can anyone help me clarify this doubt?

Comment: what is the source of frequency in your question btw ?

Comment: @Ankit vibrating string

Comment: by changing the tension aren't you producing or causing a change in the vibrating string then ?

Comment: If you change the source (tension) would you not expect the frequency to change?

Comment: Yes I get that,but due to the increase in tension velocity of the wave increases right? According to v=sqrt(T/m) where T is tension and m is linear density. And then substituting that in v=fL where f is the frequency and L is the wavelength,shouldn't L increase and not f ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two different frequencies.  The frequency of the string you are referring to is the fundamental frequency of the string.  The frequency of the source, which vibrates the string, is independent of the string itself.

The way these two frequencies are associated with each other is in the amplitude of the strings vibration.  If the source frequency is much lower than the fundamental frequency, then the string will vibrate with a relatively low amplitude.  As the source frequency approaches the fundamental frequency from below, the amplitude of the resultant vibration will increase.  The amplitude will reach a maximum when the source frequency equals the fundamental frequency, which is called resonance.  As the source frequency increases from the fundamental frequency the amplitude will again decrease.

There are actually an infinite number of frequencies associated with the string; the fundamental is just the lowest one.  Since I am assuming that you are dealing with a fixed-fixed string, the next frequency where resonance can occur is at twice the fundamental, then three times the fundamental, and so on.